# Android Firebase Removing all user data with relogin

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create users table in Firebase realtime database.However, everytime user re-logins his previously entered data is being removed or overwritten.Couldnt understand how should I change it.

```
  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {





    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {



                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registration Is Succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        final String databaseUserName=user.getDisplayName();


                        String name=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();

                        DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");


                        DatabaseReference userNameRef =  myRootRef.child(databaseUserName);


                    //after that user is redirected to the main account activity.
                        Intent accountIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,UserAccountActivity.class);
                        accountIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(accountIntent);


                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // if signing up task is unsuccesfull we do make a error indication pretty much.
                        FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException )task.getException();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Failed Registration: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.e("LoginActivity", "Failed Registration", e);

                    }


                }
            });



}
```

So once I run the code, for the very first time it works perfectly fine and say I edit&add additional user info but once the user logs out and re-enters, everything is cleared out and node is again created.

Comment: does child("Users") only have child(databaseUserName) as child?

Comment: Users is the main node which consists of users. and all users have subnodes such as email ,username,birthday and so on. and when I log in everytime, all those subnodes are being deleted and the user logged in is again created from the scracht as for the very same node.

Comment: as in my answer they are being overridden and not deleted, u need to user push to create a random id so there wont be any overridden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working version of the source code. You can use the very same code for facebook login as well. This code simply prevents user from overwriting when logging in again.

```
  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {





    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this,"Registration Is Succesfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");

                        //getting current users account
                        FirebaseUser user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        //getting the display name of the current user to store them in our real time database

                        final String databaseUserName=user.getDisplayName();


                        //creating a child called users
                        final DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");



                        //here we make a control such that, if logged in user is exist in the realtime database
                        //if not exists, then we save them , if exists we continue with the else statement and break it.
                        myRootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(databaseUserName)){

                                    DatabaseReference userNameRef =  myRootRef.child(databaseUserName);
                                    //value is also set to user display name however it doenst have to be so
                                    userNameRef.setValue(databaseUserName);



                                } else{


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });




                        //after that user is redirected to the main account activity.
                        Intent accountIntent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this,UserAccountActivity.class);
                        accountIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(accountIntent);


                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // if signing up task is unsuccesfull we do make a error indication pretty much.
                        FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException )task.getException();
                        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Failed Registration: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Log.e("LoginActivity", "Failed Registration", e);

                    }


                }
            });



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are saving the data in the database:

```
DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
DatabaseReference userNameRef =  myRootRef.child(databaseUserName);
```

Now on the second time, the data is not getting deleted or cleared, it cannot be deleted magically, the data is getting overridden. All you need to do is add a `push()` that will create a random id for each log in.

So like this:

```
DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").push();
DatabaseReference userNameRef =  myRootRef.child(databaseUserName)
```

Edit:

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Activity_name_here.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
```

Comment: if i use this piece of code , it turns out that, everytime I log in  and log out  new node is created for the same user with different random Id.so basically push generates different keys and stores them in the users table.

Comment: yes, that way it is not overridden. If you don't want that then send the data of the user to the database in sign up page. Then in sign in page just check if the user is authenticated and if he exists in the database

Comment: that's the problem with it, firebase google auth method doesn't have two distinct functions called sign up and sign in. it uses the same function to register and sign in the users. therefore if I run the code everything is overwritten

Comment: it does have, I have wrote it in the edit. In the else you can send the data to the database

Comment: thank you very much but as you can see this is for creating an account using regular email. I'm referring to googleAuth

Comment: I think you can do this, in sign in using google check if it exists in your database. If it does go to the second page if it doesnt then send it to the database. This will surely work. So inside this `if (task.isSuccessful()) {` in your code you check if data exists, if it does go to secondactivity, if it doesnt send it to database and go to next activity.

Comment: @theroglu did you understand how?

Comment: yup latest comment on yours fixed my problem pretty much down I'll share the required code. thank you very much.

Comment: @theroglu okay if my answer was helpful, please upvote or mark it as correct. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.